# Separating services in Ionic app doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-services

I am struggling to successfully separate services into individual files. I am trying to do it the same way as I have my controllers, that is:

in index.html, I have these lines

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/Service1.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/Ctrl1.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('testApp', ['ionic', 'testApp.controllers', 'ionic.service.core', 'testApp.services'])
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('testApp.controllers', []);
```

Ctrl1.js

```
angular.module('testApp.controllers')
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

However, using the same approach for services does not work and I will get an error for Unknown Provider.

services.js

```
angular.module('testApp.services', ['ionic.utils']);
```

Service1.js

```
angular.module('testApp.services')
.factory('testService' function () {
return {}});
```

I tried also with

```
angular.module('testApp.services', ['ionic.utils'])
.factory('testService' function () {
return {}});
```

What am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: If I include the code from Service1.js without the first line and semi-colon in the main services.js file, everything works perfectly. Tried searching around for possible solution but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code you provide in your question was copied directly from your `.js` files then the issue is a simple missing comma in your **Service1.js** file:

```
angular.module('testApp.services')
.factory('testService', function () {
//                    ^ missing comma
  return {};
});
```

Same issue for your other try to fix in **Service.js**